# Is there an equivalent for “Too soon!” in French?

Tags: expressions, traduction

“Too soon” is often said when someone makes an offensive joke about a sad or tragic event very quickly after it happened when there hasn’t been time for any grief or it’s still very serious.

ex.

“Drunk driving? Well, I guess you could say she died doing what she loved...”

“Too soon, man.”

Is there an equivalent in French for this?

Comment: Because you have a sense of humor, you laugh.

Comment: @Reese testing someone's sense of humor this way in a moment of grief can be very hurtful

Comment: Also note that the "Too soon" can be used even if you find it funny, to accentuate the "crassy" side of the joke.

Answer (score 3):

There is no equivalent phrase to use in that situation. You would react with a general statement like:

> Un peu de décence !
>
> C'est pas drôle.
>
> Ce n'est pas le moment.
>
> C'est totalement déplacé.

Comment: Aside from "ce n'est pas le moment", these express outage but don't reflect the sense of "too soon" which is a bit like "I'd find this joke funny if it weren't for the recent circumstances".

Answer (score 2):

It could be something like

> Trop tôt pour en rire

In English the expression "Too soon" is already understood to mean "Too soon to joke about it", but in French you'd need to phrase it explicitly.

Example usage: http://m.leparisien.fr/espace-premium/culture-loisirs/trop-tot-pour-en-rire-21-11-2015-5298019.php

Comment: +1. Also: "Trop tôt pour cette blague", maybe?

Comment: I'll add "Trop tôt", shorten could also be understood in some conditions: users are shortening sentences (we are becoming "lazy", that's a fact), users have some English knowledge (watching TV shows in English, etc.), or it's in response to another reproach, like a remark on the previous joke, so it's implicitly saying "la blague est arrivée trop tôt": Like saying the joke,  followed by a remark/void, and in response of that remark/void, constating it's too soon.

Answer (score 1):

We push a void in the conversation to make the guy who say that realize what he said ...

Answer (score 0):

If the speaker is used to the concept, I generally simply translate as "Trop tôt.", even though I will most often keep the term in English and say "Too soon".